# probability of alphabet

Tags: probability

the problem states that 26 letters A,B...Z are arranged in a random order.

1) what is the probability that A comes before B in the random order?

2) what is the probability that A comes before Z in the random order?

so for the first one i know that total number of possible arrangements is 26!, then for A to be before B we would start with A being in the first position then we would have 25 ways for it to be before B, then move A one position then we would only be left with 24 ways, keep going like that, which means there is 25! ways for A to be before B, so probability is 25!/26! or 1/26, same method and answer would go for question 2. am i right or did i make mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your reasoning and your answer are correct.

Another way to see this is to see that the probability that A comes before B is the same as the probability that A comes before some other letter.  There are 25 letters that are not A.  But there is the case where A is the last letter.  There are 26 cases then, each having the same number of outcomes.  The probability of each is 1/26.

Answer (score 1):

This way of counting is ok but cumbersome. Take any permutation and swap $A$ with $B$, then you get a new permutation. That is, swapping $A\leftrightarrow B$ (or $A\leftrightarrow Z$) gives us a bijection between th permutations with $A$ before $B$ and those with $B$ before $A$. Hence their numbers are the same.